# while statement executed infinitely

Tags: jquery, while-loop, jquery-animate

I have a sldieshow plugin for pictures using `animation()`, that I want it to work only on hover event, and reset images to their default positions on mouseout
only to two problems am facing, are that I can't stop the animation, and the browser blocks of excessive memory use
here's what i use :

```
$('.slideshow').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('li:first').attr('flag', '');
  $(this).slide()
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul').stop(true); //if you keep the mouse a little bit long it wont stop
  // and this while statement blocks the browser
  while ($('[flag]').index() != 0) {
    $(this).slide(1) // the parameter 1 here is to slide only once
  }
})
```

for the sake of a full understanding here's my [**[DEMO]**](https://jsfiddle.net/AmineTbaik/yfk45k86/)
so what I stated above is what I actually expect, but it gets stack instead
why this is happening
note : I didn't use any increment because the slide plugin only gets executed once, and then it will be re-executed when the condition is not satisfied

Comment: Try a combination of `setTimeout` and a recursive function. Test for hover at the top of the function.

Comment: some like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/AmineTbaik/yfk45k86/2/) ?
the index is always returned -1 for unknown reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want something like this (please complete with actual code):

```
function changeSlide(ss) {
    if ($(ss).hasClass('hover') {
        // transition to the next slide
    }
    setTimeout(function() {changeSlide(ss)}, 5000 /*milliseconds*/);
}
$('.slideshow').on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
    changeSlide(this);
}).on('mouseout',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

[Modified demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/w96fwvjn/)